# Software to create FEN notation?

Tags: fen

I am new to FEN notation. I understand its importance for describing position of pieces on board. I also understand FEN notations after reading about it in Wikipedia. However, it is a time taking procedure to write it down manually. I am looking for a software or web site, which allows me to place the pieces on the board, and then create FEN notation automatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I am looking for a software **or web site**, which allows me to place the pieces on the board, and then create FEN notation automatically.

I personally use [this site](http://www.apronus.com/chess/wbeditor.php) for that.

It is free, and it is **an online tool.**

[image]

**REMARKS:**

*If you wish to put that FEN in our diagram you paste that code like this:*

1. Press space bar 4 times;
2. Type square brackets ( `[]` );
3. Type `fen ""` inside the brackets ( `[fen ""]` );
4. Paste your code inside the `""` ( `[fen "Your FEN goes here"]` );

*If you decide to input variations you need to do this:*

5. Press enter twice;
6. Press space bar 4 times;
7. Input moves;

Here is an example:

[image]

*If you have further question leave a comment and I will help you. Also read [this thread](https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/373/can-i-post-an-annotated-pgn-chess-board-in-chess-stackexchange-com).*

**END OF REMARKS**

Hopefully this answer helps you.

Best regards.

Comment: @KurioZ7: Always glad to help. Best regards until next time :)

Comment: Position setup does not have the Generate FEN option.

Answer (score 3):

SCID will do it.  Create a position using `Edit->Setup Board`. There's a text box at the bottom of the setup window with the FEN.  Or, if you've been playing against the computer, you can just say `Edit->Copy FEN` to get the board's current position.

Answer (score 3):

I use the [Lichess Board editor](https://lichess.org/editor). It has drag and drop, and click and place and it provides the FEN to any position.

Answer (score 2):

I´m in a similar matter.
But what I tried to have is a fen list, not just a single fen line.
That is: having a PGN file, have the complete list of fen, one line per position. 
If for example the game had 40 moves, I need the 40 positions that ocured during the game.

In fact I found one program that do it: pgn2fen: 
http://pgn2fen.downv.com/Windows-software-download/pgn2fen
It has a bug, it does not make the fen for the last position.

Answer (score 1):

Python has now a `chess` module, which is able to parse FEN (among other formats), and also output any position to FEN, EDP, PGN and also SVG format. It is as simple as `F = input(); B = chess.Board(F)` to read in a FEN. Then you can easily extract information or modify the positions, and write it back to a file using `B.fen(en_passant='fen')` or `B.epd(en_passant='fen', ...)`; to write back a PGN, use `chess.pgn`; see [chapter "Writing" of the documentation](https://python-chess.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pgn.html#writing), similar for producing SVG.

You can find more information at:

- https://python-chess.readthedocs.io
- https://github.com/niklasf/python-chess